# Linking a cell to a tab within an Excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2011. One of my workbooks contains a tab. I want that tab to open when I click a link. The link should be in a cell in the same workbook. How can I create such a link?

Comment: Can you explain you question more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a Mac on which to test this but I believe the instructions [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/hyperlinks/create1_2011.php) are what you need:

1. Right click on the cell where the hyperlink should go and select Hyperlink from the popup menu.

   [image]
2. Click on the Documents tab then the Locate button.

   [image]
3. Enter the cell reference that the hyperlink should point to. Adjust the sheet name appropriately.

   [image]

   You should now see something like the following:

   [image]
4. Enter the hyperlink text in the Display field.

   [image]

   You'll end up with something like this:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=SheetName!CellReference
```

Example: =Sheet1!A1
This would link whatever cell you type this in to cell A1 on Sheet1, assuming your workbook has a Sheet1.

Comment: Is it possible to have text in the cell + the link?

Comment: Actually, this is not what I'm looking for. I want the tab to open when I click the link.

Answer (score -1):

To add, in Excel 2016 on Windows, if you add a regular cell reference to the link like '=Sheet1!A1' then that link will break if you rename the sheet/tab. You can add a workbook scope named range to the sheet to open, then use that named range as the link reference, and then you can change the name of the sheet to open at will.